# Selecting a script from a Gameobject[] in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I Have a game that I am developing, it is a TBS, and will have many creatures involved. I wanted to store all the creatures I have at runtime in an array, which I have successfully done. However, I need to be able to call all scripts from those array items, so: **How can I call differently named scripts on GameObjects in an array all at once, OR what alternatives do I have?** For background on its use, think about Initiative in D&D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using inheritance or interfaces, you can create an array of your base class/interface, and add all your creatures into that array (which you say you have an array of all these creatures).

You would simply loop through all the elements in the array, and call the respective method.

**For example:**

```
//not a cut-and-paste example, but gives you the general idea.
foreach(var _creature in Array)
{
   _creature.Die();
}
```

However, if you are trying to call a different method for each one, you may find this will not work for you.

If you want to break it down further, you can try and switch on the type and then call a specific method for each type, but then it isn't a truly generic class:

**For example:**

```
//not a cut-and-paste example, but gives you the general idea.
foreach(var _creature in Array)
{
   switch typeof(_creature):
      case LowLevel:
        _creature.Flee();
        break;
      case MidLevel:
        _creature.Guard();
        break;
      case HighLevel:
        _creature.Attack();
        break;
      default:
        _creature.Idle();
        break;
}
```

An example of a polymorphic implementation:

```
public abstract class Combatant : MonoBehaviour
{
    //for arguments sake, we are only going to have speed property, attack method which
    //all instances have to implement, and a defend which only some might implement their
    //own method for (the rest default to the base class)
    int speed {get;set;}

    //Need to have this method in derived classes
    //We don't define a body, because the derived class needs to define it's own
    protected abstract void Attack();

    //Can be overriden in derived class, but if not, falls back to this implementation
    protected virtual void Defend()
    {
        speed *= 0.5; //half speed when defending
    }
}

public class MonsterA : Combatant
{
    protected override void Attack()
    {
        //attack code goes here for MonsterA
    }

    //to access speed, we simply need to use base.speed
    public void SomethingElse()
    {
        base.speed *= 1.25;
    }

    //notice we don't have to provide an implementation for Defend, but we can still access it by calling base.Defend(); - this will then run the base classes implementation of it.
}

public class MonsterB : Combatant
{
    protected override void Attack()
    {
        //attack code goes here for MonsterB
    }

    //Assume this is a 'heavier' class 'monster', speed will go down more than standard when defending
    protected override void Defend()
    {
        base.speed *= 0.3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worth noting, if your array is `Array<GameObject>`, then you will not have these methods exposed to you unless you cast them to the type you are 100% sure they are.

Comment: Okay, that's a new way to look at it. However, Here's an example of what I'm trying to do `public GameObject[] Combatants;` and then `Combatants = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("tagname");` and finally be able to get the scripts from all of those items. Is there any way of doing that specifically?

Comment: By 'get the scripts', what do you mean? Do you mean you want to call a method from each of your `Combatants`? Or do you want to know what scripts are attached to those `Combatant` game objects? Your method most definitely works, and it will return an array of `GameObject` - but you must know that it will be of type `GameObject`, meaning unless you cast it to the type or assign it to a typed variable, you will not be able to access the methods that are on the `Combatant` because they do not exist on the `GameObject` class.

Comment: So, each of these combatants, while they do have different names, also have different C# scripts attached that tell what there stats are. I need to gather all of the scripts at once so that I can compare a variable call Speed to decide something similar to initiative, which would tell which "combatants" make the first move.

Comment: And in your script, these are all `ClassName : MonoBehavior`? I would suggest, if they all share a common property/properties/methods, to have an Interface (ie. `ICombatant`) that all the other `combatant`s implement, which then enforce that all `Combatant`s have, for example, a speed variable, an attack method, etc.. Then you can create an Array<ICombatant> and return all objects that implement this interface. Then you can easily compare this variable against other base scripts (ie. `MonsterA : MonoBehavior, ICombatant`, `MonsterB : MonoBehavior, ICombatant`). Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: It does, just how would I do `ICombatant`? I've never had to create an interface let alone throw it into an Array.

Comment: It's like a class, but it has no implementation of the method. `public interface ICombatant : MonoBehaviour { int speed { get;set;} void Attack(); etc. etc. }`. Notice how Attack() has no body - when you implement the interface, it will enforce the interface (like a contract) that the class implementing the interface needs to have those properties and/or methods declared. Those then have their own implementation of the code. Then in the script, simply have something like this `ICombatant combatant[] = Object.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(ICombatant)) as Combatant;` and compare your variables.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_interfaces.htm are useful in this scenario.

Comment: Do you think it could be accomplished with polymorphism, or is interfacing the best option in terms of speed?

Comment: Most definitely can be achieved with polymorphism. I simply suggested an Interface for simplicity hehe. A base class that another class derives from is my personal preference, because you can both define default behaviour or your derived class can implement it's own behaviour. You can simply create an array of your base class type, and all your derived classes will be able to be stored in that array - and because they all inherit the same base class, each will have the methods and variables shared among them.

Comment: See my updated answer for an idea of an implementation of a base/derived class structure.

Comment: Thanks, I think I found a way to do what I need. I figured my first time making a TBS would be difficult, but at least I'm able to find help, so my gratitude is high for your answer : )